# How to check list of strings parameter type from isinstance() method

Tags: python, type-hinting

I want to try to handle the parameter type passed to the function by using isinstance() function. Basically, i want to check that whether passed list to the function contains only string or not. So, I wrote function as

```
def fun(parameter: list[str]):
    #want to check parameter type here
```

After getting the list, I want to ensure that it contains only strings. So, is there any way to check this from **isinstance()** function? Otherwise i have to make custom check by looping through the list.

Comment: Type hints aren't enforced, so you need a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an assertion, but yes, I think you need a loop

```
def fun(parameter:list[str]):
    assert all(isinstance(s, str) for s in parameter)
```

Comment: Yes, it can be done easily with the loop but I was in search of any other method. Seems i should go with the loop only.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an odd, roundabout way of doing it, but here's how you could get away without using a loop. I prefer @OneCricketeer's answer in general though.

```py
import numpy as np


def fun(parameter: list[str]):
    assert list(np.array(parameter, dtype=str)) == parameter
   ...
```

Passing `dtype=str` will cause any non-string items in `parameter` to be converted to strings in the resulting array, which you can then convert back to a list and compare to the original. The two will be equal only if all items were strings already.

You could also use [`np.array_equal()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) instead of wrapping the array in `list()` and comparing with `==`, which would be more efficient if your `parameter` list is very large.

Comment: Why use *numpy* for that?

Comment: Python `array` also can only hold a single type

Comment: @OneCricketeer Not strings, though. To be clear: What I meant was `list(map(str, parameter))`. (And of course both fail if there's an element which is not a string but which claims to equal its string representation.)

Comment: @Kelly Oh, thanks. Never really used them, but I see the docs do say "numeric values"

Answer (score -3):

You can use 2 methods:
**Method 1: Using the built-in function of python3 i.e isinstance().**\

*example:*

```
def fun(parameter: list[str]):
 return isinstance(parameter, (list, str))
```

This will return the **True** or **False**. It will check parameter is list or string or a list of strings.

**Method 2: create the custom function to check the type.**

*example:*

```
def fun(parameter:list[str]):
     if type(parameter) == list:
            for i in parameter:
                 if type(i) != str:
                       return False
            return True
     return False
```

The logic behind the above code is simple it will check whether the parameter is list or not if a list will send False. If it is list then it will check the contains of the list are true or not. If they are true it simply returns True.

Comment: Wont your first option check a list **or** a str? Not exclusively a *list of strings*? In other words, a list of ints would also be valid.

Comment: Don't use `type(..) == list` to check if something is a list.

Comment: Yes, first method returns true on list of int also.

Comment: Right, because `isinstance(x, (type1, type2, ...))` checks if `x` is an instance of _any of the types in the tuple_. It works for a list of strings or a list of ints because both of them are lists. The problem is it'll also work if `parameter` is a _string!_, which is not what OP wants